# Grails app: own query language for data stored in DB and files + full text search (Hibernate Search, Compass etc)

Tags: lucene, full-text-search, hibernate-search, compass-lucene

I have an application which stored short descriptive data in DB and lots of related textual data in text files.

I would like to add "advanced search" for DB. I was thinking about adding own query language like JIRA does (Jira Query Language).  Then I thought about having full text search across those textual files (less priority).

Wondering which tool will better suite me to implement that faster and simpler.

I most of all I want to provide users with ability to write their own queries instead of using  elements to specify search filters.

Thanks

UPD. I save dates in DB and most of varchar fields contain one word strings.

UPD2. Apache Derby is used right now.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Searchable plugin for Grails.

http://www.grails.org/plugin/searchable